# Relation Between Pharmacist and Patient in access 2016

Tags: database, ms-access, database-design, relation, ms-access-2016

I am creating a Pharmacy Database in Access 2016. It is my school Project and first Database Project.

My first problem is that we know that a Pharmacist can have many Patients, so it means that the relationship between Pharmacist and Patient is one-to-many. So in order to create a one-to-many relation, I made `Pharmacist_ID` as Primary Key.

Now the problem is that we know that the relation of Address and Patient is one-to-one, so how can I accomplish this task?

Another problem is that I already have the address, the city and nationality which are linked with the `Pharmacist_ID`. Can I link these tables with `Patient_ID`?

I am confused because the data-type of `Pharmacist_ID` is `Auto-Number`. The `Patient_ID` of the first Patient will be 1 and then `Pharmacist_ID` of the first Pharmacist will also 1 so what will happen?

Again, I am on MS-Access 2016.
[This is the Picture of The RelationShip and you can see the Details of my Tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HlUN1.png)

Regards,

Arslan Iftikhar

[image]

[This is for Thomas G check it out Thomas do you think I am doing right or wrong](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kVAqt.png)

Comment: Well you'd have different columns to hold the pharmacist id and the patient id, so they wouldn't conflict with each other. You'll need to show some code to get more help here.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I edited your post to help with the English a little and to break the questions out into separate paragraphs so they're easier to see for the reader. I also added two tags, one for database design, because that's what you're doing here, and one for Access 2016 because that's the product you're working with. They're also more popular tags than the ones you started with, so more people should see your question now.

Comment: I'm not sure about the best way to do this in Access, but if you could edit your question to show us the structure of the tables you have so far (`Pharmacist`, `Patient`, and `Address` from the looks of it) that would be helpful as well.

Comment: I have added the Picture of my tables Eric Brandt

Comment: 1 Patient can have many Pharmacists, so the relationship is m-to-m IMHO.

Comment: see my edited answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I will make below changes to Address table:**

1. I will prefer creating one common table for Address which also has `City` and `Nationality` (for simplicity else link them like image 2 below)
2. Added field `PID` as Number where you can save Pharmacist or Patient ID
3. Added field `Ptype` as Number where to save value 1 when Pharmacist and 2 when patient, so we can easily differentiate using this field.

**Image 1**
[image]

**Image 2**

[image: Image 2]

Comment: what about the relation between Patient and Pharmacist

Comment: You can create a junction table.

Answer (score 1):

A few design mistakes in your approach.
I will list a few things I think about, and try to train you to raise the right questions.

---

> My first problem is that we know that a Pharmacist can have many
>   Patients, so it means that the relationship between Pharmacist and
>   Patient is one-to-many

The first part is only partially correct, which makes the second part incorrect and might lead to a big design failure.

In a normal world:

- a Pharmacist can have many Patients
- a Patient can have many Pharmacists

Isn't it ?

Thus you have a m-to-m relationship. How do you solve this? With an intermediate table storing the relation between patients and pharmacists.

The only exception to this, is if you make your software for only one Pharmacist, then your 1-to-m approach will work, but then I dont see any reason to have a Phamarcist table :)

---

> Now the problem is that we know that the relation of Address and
>   Patient is one-to-one, so how can I accomplish this task?

Are you really sure about this? What happens in such cases then:

- Patients members of the same family (living in the same house).
- Patients for which the billing address is not the same as home address.
- Patients that are also Pharmacists.
- Patients owning several houses.

Those are very common cases. If you go the 1-1, you'll end up with A LOT of doubles in your address table.

The REAL reason for which we almost always put addresses in  seperate table, is that adresses are rarely one-to-one in information systems. If it was one-to-one, there would be no real reason to store them in additional tables.

---

> I am confused because the data-type of Pharmacist_ID is Auto-Number.
>   The Patient_ID of the first Patient will be 1 and then Pharmacist_ID
>   of the first Pharmacist will also 1 so what will happen?

And that is a good question, which should have led you to the design mistake above. You should not have a 1-1 between address and something else (Patient or Pharmacist).

In your Patient AND Pharmacists tables, you should have an AddressID refering the ID in the address table. If you want to let the opportunity to the pharamacists to store:

- Home Address
- Billing Address
- Holiday Address
- Whatever additional address

You should either :

- Create an AddressID field in your Patient (and eventually Pharmacist table) for each of the address types.
- If you really have many types for your addresses, it's better to create an intermediate table handling m-to-m between address and Patient/Pharmacists, with at least a Type column in it.

---

**Edit. Reactions on your new model.**

I guess the point of your CITY table is to have a big list of cities? That you can use for comboboxes for instance? If you go that way, you might do the same for countries, or states/regions. That's fine, BUT : the city_id, (and eventually State_ID and Country_ID), should be part of the ADDRESS table.  It doesnt make sense to have an address with only a street, house number and po box. That's incomplete, an address should also contain a zip code, city and country to be complete.

Comment: Thanks for correcting the Mistakes and guiding me on my project actually it's my first school project so I don't have any kind of experience in Data Base.

Comment: well, I have edited my post and added new pic check it out the Problem is that How can I make the relation between Pharmacist_Salary and Pharmacist as the relation between them is one-to-one. And how can i create relation between Contact or mobile and Pharmacist  is one-to-many. One Person can have many numbers but one number cannot be used by many Persons so the relation is one-to-many. See the Image i added in my question. i am editing my post and adding the image

Comment: ok let's say I added the city, country, address in one table and create m-to-m relation but what about the Pharmacist and Pharmacist_Salary how can I create one-to-one relation between them.